# Is there any way to figure out table item's index?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

my tableviewer contains a list of table item, if i know the item's key, could i get index of this item ? i dont want to iterate the list of table items due to performance concern.

Any hints will be more than welcome!

```
    private void setFocus(TableViewer tableViewer , Item currentItem){
    int selection = 0; 
    tableViewer.getInput();
    List<Item> items=(List<Item>)tableViewer.getInput();
    for(Item item: items){
        if(ticket.getId()==currentItem.getId()){
            tableViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(tableViewer.getElementAt(selection)),true);
            break;
        }
        selection++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the index TableViewer doesn't generally use the index for anything. What do you mean by 'key'?

Comment: i am working on tableitem, then i need to refresh table, by tableview.setInput and after that i need to set focus on one specific table item , each of my table item has a unqiue id.

Comment: If you are using TableViewer you should not touch TableItem - TableViewer manages the items and will override your changes at some point. You should do everything using the TableViewer APIs. and your content and label providers.

Comment: if i knoew the item's id, could I directly setfocus on this item instead of looping through the item list? please refer to snippet of the code

Comment: If you need to be able to look something up by an id use a HashMap to get the corrent item, but this really won't be a perfornance issue unless you have thousands of items in the list.

Comment: No, i want to setSelection on item based on item's id which I knew in advance already.